# Twilio API in angular8 Not Authorized " 401 Unauthorized" but working fine on Postman

Tags: angular, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I am trying to call Twilio API from Angular8 Application but i am getting below mentioned Error
[image]

Error Text is
`message: "Http failure response for https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms: 401 Unauthorized"`
`detail: "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect."`
Code that i am using in angular is

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic QUM2NjNiMmY4ZTM3NWY1NjUwMjg4ZDE4NzMYzA==',
      "UniqueName": Name
    });
    return this.httpclient.post('https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms', { headers: headers });
  }
```

I have also try to change the `Content-Type` as `application/json`
but still no success

Same Code i am using in postman and it is working fine

[image]

My ultimate goal is to create room and join as participant through video

Comment: The second parameter of a post call is the post body, not the options with the header. Read the docs: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

Comment: thank you, I have figured out the issue from your comment it was related to the body which I have provided as null,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend that you do not make this API call from your front-end application. To do so, you need to embed your credentials in the front-end and a malicious user would be able to extract them and abuse your account.

In your case, you have tried to include the base 64 encoded parameters as the `Authorization` header and I was able to extract your Account SID (though not your auth token, which is good for your security now!).

If you want to make requests to the Twilio API, I recommend you do that from your server side, that way you can keep your credentials secure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable feedback, I have one confusion if I use backend call i.e. .NetAPIs using IIS server will it slow down the server response or network?

Actually our aim is to call APIs for video streaming and I am afraid to use our own server and network bandwidth

Comment: The API you are calling there is to create the Video room, the actual video call itself takes place between the participants (and Twilio if you are using group rooms) but not your server. You already have to create an access token on your server so that participants can join the call, so performing this API request on the server too should not be a problem.

Comment: so what i understand is to follow the below flow 

1. Create API in .net server for creating rooms and getting access token so it will secure my credentials 

2. Utilize access token in (Angular Client Side) so that participants can join the call directly from Twillio APIs 

Please correct if i got it wrong

Comment: That is exactly right! 

Comment: Can you please guide me More about Video Streaming in Angular 
Actually I want to create One to One video streaming session 

1. https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms this API will create room ()
2. API example for getting Access Token (Type of data/Payload)
3. API for connecting to the Room (Type of data/Payload)

Comment: We don't have a lot of examples in Angular I'm afraid. It's best to check the [Twilio Video JS docs and examples](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript) and try to build from there. There's also the [API reference](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.21.0/docs/) which will tell you about all the objects in the system.